# "Mir war nicht danach."

Tags: translation

I happen to know that

> Mir war nicht danach.

... translates to

> I didn't feel like it.

... but I would have never been able to figure it out on my own.

Is it short for something?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The adverb "*zumute*" is key here: "*zumute*" can be placed at the end of a sentence to convey the idea of "*how you feel*", "*what kind of mood you are in*". The sentence construction with "*zumute*" requires the omitted, impersonal subject "*es*". You can say, for instance:

> Ihm ist im Moment nicht nach Zuhören **zumute**.

=== "Right now, he's not in the mood to listen to anything {any word of advice}."

> Ihm ist im Moment nicht nach Zuhören.
>
> Ihm ist im Moment nicht danach. – {the construction used in your example}

Another way to express this idea is:

> Ihm steht der Sinn nicht nach Zuhören.

You can also place an adjective like "*wehmütig*" instead of "*nach* + noun":

> Wenn ich darauf zurückblicke, wird mir ganz wehmütig zumute.

Comment: The last example "wehmütig zumute" sounds very unusual to me (I'd expect it more in a Goethe text than modern language). Also, generally, the word "zumute" sounds a bit oldfashioned to me, as well as "Ihm steht der Sinn nicht...". I believe the answer would be improved if you'd show when you would use these constructs in modern times (i.e., some of them would be good in daily speach or in emails, the others more in formal written texts).

Comment: I also think the last example takes away from the answer. It puts too much emphasis on "wehmütig", which is just one of many words to be used with "zumute" and as an example does not provide additional value.

Answer (score 6):

"Mir ist ..." is a way to express feelings.

For example:

> Mir ist kalt.

I am cold.

> Mir ist schlecht.

I feel sick.

Taking this into account, "Mir ist nach ..." = "I feel like ..." is not as weird as it may look on first sight.

Comment: But how does "danach" work in the sentence?

Comment: @BruceWayne  It references something that was mentioned earlier. It won't work without a context, be it walking, listening, flying, eating...Mir war nicht nach Essen zumute. Ich hätte etwas gegessen, aber mir war nicht danach (zumute).

Comment: "Danach" ("after it", here: "like it") is one of those words which combine a preposition and a pronoun. Similar words: "Davon" ("From/of it"), "dagegen" ("against it"), "darauf" ("on it").

Comment: "towards" would work - "danach zumute" is similar to "inclined towards". Even the slightly arrogant/sarcastic tone of a correctly used "inclined towards" is preserved if the full "danach zumute" is used :)