# "Es ist einem nach Etwas" Bedeutung?

Tags: phrase

Was ist die Bedeutung dieses Satzes?

> Es ist einem nach etwas.

Es steht in meinem Kursbuch ohne Kontext.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Mir war nicht danach."](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41790/mir-war-nicht-danach)

Comment: Kein Duplikat, da Frage deutsch und verlinkte Antwort englisch. Passiert mir manchmal.

Comment: Are there  other sentences/ examples around this sentence? What is the chapter about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beispiel:

> Mir wär jetzt nach 'nem schönen kühlen Bier!

= "Ich hätte jetzt echt Lust auf auf ein richtig schönes kühles Bier."

> Mir war nicht nach Party, ich wollte allein sein.

= "Mir war nicht nach Party und Feiern zumute."

Gut möglich, dass dieses "*jemandem ist nicht nach ...*" sich von "*jemandem ist nicht nach ... zumute*" herleitet. Dafür sagt man auch "*nicht zu etwas aufgelegt sein*" oder "*nicht in der Stimmung sein + zu + Infinitiv*".

Ähnliche Bedeutung, aber veraltend: *jemandem steht der Sinn nach*. Soweit es sich um starken Durst auf ein bestimmtes Getränk handelt, sagt man auch

> Ich könnte jetzt echt einen Schluck / Drink / ... vertragen.